# Rails 3.2.13 upgrade and jruby/openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jruby-openssl

After upgrading to Rails 3.2.13, I've started getting errors about jruby/openssl.

```
(LoadError) no such file to load -- jruby/openssl
```

I'm using JRuby 1.6.7, jruby-openssl 0.8.6, and Rails 3.2.13.

Has anyone been able to solve this?

Comment: you have the gem in your gem file right? and you have run bundle install, right?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: This app was working before the rails upgrade (was on 3.2.12). The only thing I changed was the rails version in Gemfile and reran bundle install.

Comment: look at this.. I would try using jruby 1.7.2 or .3 but also look at this:require 'jruby/openssl/gem_only' info: http://jruby.org/openssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRuby-OpenSSL version 0.8.x is incompatible with anything less than JRuby 1.7.x.

JRuby-OpenSSL version 0.7.x can still be used with JRuby 1.6.x.

Downgrading the jruby-openssl gem version should resolve this issue.